# Staging Module for Sitecore 7

Tags: module, sitecore, upgrade, staging, sitecore7

We are upgarding a site from Sitecore 6.2 to Sitecore 7.The 6.2 Version of the site make use of Staging Module and I believe that we do not have a Staging Module for Sitecore Version 7.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Please let me know the available alternatives for Staging Module that can be used for Sitecore 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Sitecore's [SDN page of Staging Module](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Staging.aspx):

> NOTE: When using CMS 6.3 or later, DO NOT use the Staging module. 
>   Please refer to the CMS 6.3 Scaling Guide for alternative
>   instructions.

The scaling guide for Sitecore 7 can be found [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/sitecore_search_scaling%20guide_sc7-a4.pdf).

Comment: I totally agree with Trayek,you don't need Staging Module after you update, you just need to follow instructions from Scaling Guide.

Comment: Thank you Trayek and sitecore climber.